# How do I call sh file daily? ora_backup

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, backup

My db version is oracle 12c. OS: oracle linux

I have working sh file

```
  export  ORACLE_SID=mydborcl
export  ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/db_1
export  PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
export  NLS_LANG='AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8'

expdp adminuser/Mypassword@mydborcl schemas=adminuser directory=my_db1 dumpfile=adminuser_`date +%Y%m%d`.dmp logfile=adminuser_`date +%Y%m%d`.log
```

How can I call that sh file daily or weekly?
How to set it automatically delete the old backup?

Answer (score 0):

you can setup cronjob for rman backup database daily or weekly.

if you want to keep backup for a day or a week, just set retain policy to a week or a day, depend on your need.

Comment: Could you provide me how can I setup cronjob for rman backup database daily or weekly?

Comment: if you run in unix/linux,  you can run crontab -e , this will open crontab , crontab you can place how often, you are running scipt, that is how you schedule rman backup job. see https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html

Comment: the following is rman cronjob example. see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/139309/cron-and-rman-backups

Answer (score 0):

please see following steps, that will tell you how to setup rman backup using cron

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/139309/cron-and-rman-backups

Comment: please see the sh file.. how to call it daily or weekly?